# Message body empty on quickblox ios in xamarin native c#

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, quickblox

i've translated the quickblox's sample app for Xamarin forms in Xamarin iOS and Android native.
Everything works "except" that the retrieving of the message fails.

I send the message from one client, and the event is catched from the other chat occupant:

```
XMPP: DispatchEvents ====> <message id="580735ed335fb760ae0017ec" xmlns="jabber:client" from="18029700-46533@chat.quickblox.com/1220770403-quickblox-68179" type="chat" to="18976912-46533@chat.quickblox.com"><extraParams xmlns="jabber:client"><save_to_history>1</save_to_history><dialog_id>5800aea1a28f9a1c1f000010</dialog_id><message_id>580735ed335fb760ae0017ec</message_id><date_sent>1476867565</date_sent></extraParams><body>test+message</body><thread>5800aea1a28f9a1c1f000010</thread></message>
XMPP: OnMessageReceived ====>  From: 18029700 To: 18976912 Body:  DateSent 1476867565 FullXmlMessage: <message id="580735ed335fb760ae0017ec" xmlns="jabber:client" from="18029700-46533@chat.quickblox.com/1220770403-quickblox-68179" type="chat" to="18976912-46533@chat.quickblox.com"><extraParams xmlns="jabber:client"><save_to_history>1</save_to_history><dialog_id>5800aea1a28f9a1c1f000010</dialog_id><message_id>580735ed335fb760ae0017ec</message_id><date_sent>1476867565</date_sent></extraParams><body>test+message</body><thread>5800aea1a28f9a1c1f000010</thread></message>
```

as you can see the Body part into the event OnMessageReceived is empty!
But the html part in the end of this snippet contains the message "test+message"

this is the PrivateChat Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using QbChat.Pcl.Repository;
using Quickblox.Sdk.GeneralDataModel.Models;
using Quickblox.Sdk.Modules.ChatXmppModule;
using Quickblox.Sdk.Modules.UsersModule.Models;
using UIKit;
using Xmpp.Im;

namespace KeepInTouch.iOS
{
    public partial class PrivateChat : BaseChat
    {
        PrivateChatManager privateChatManager;

        public PrivateChat(string dialogId, string nibname) : base(dialogId, nibname) { }

        public async override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewWillAppear(animated);
            AppDelegate.R.NavController.SetNavigationBarHidden(true, true);
            await MessageProvider.Reconnect();
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base_tb_chat = tb_chat;
            base_txt_chat = txt_chat;
            base.ViewDidLoad();
            view_top.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromPatternImage(UIImage.FromFile("navbar_top_kit.png"));
            tb_chat.TableFooterView = new UIView();
            IsBusyIndicatorVisible = true;
            var dialog = Database.Instance().GetDialog(dialogId);
            var opponentId = dialog.OccupantIds.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).First(id => id != QbChat.UserId);
            ChatXmppClient xmpc = QbChat.QbProvider.GetXmppClient();
            privateChatManager = xmpc.GetPrivateChatManager(opponentId, dialogId);
            privateChatManager.MessageReceived += OnMessageReceived;
            DialogName = dialog.Name;

            //xmpc.MessageReceived += OnMessageReceived;

            btn_chat.TouchUpInside += async delegate {
                await SendMessageCommandExecute();
                txt_chat.Text = "";
            };

            txt_chat.ShouldReturn += (textField) => {
                textField.ResignFirstResponder();
                return true;
            };

            txt_chat.EditingChanged += async delegate {
                MessageText = txt_chat.Text;
                await MessageProvider.Reconnect();
            };

            btn_back.TouchUpInside += delegate {
                DismissViewController(false, null);
            };

            IsBusyIndicatorVisible = true;

            Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => {
                var users = await QbChat.QbProvider.GetUsersByIdsAsync(dialog.OccupantIds);
                var opponentUser = users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id != QbChat.UserId);
                if (opponentUser != null && opponentUser.BlobId.HasValue) {
                    await QbChat.QbProvider.GetImageAsync(opponentUser.BlobId.Value).ContinueWith((task, result) => {
                        //var bytes = 
                        task.ConfigureAwait(true).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
                }
                opponentUsers = new List<User> { opponentUser };
                await LoadMessages();
                InvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                    IsBusyIndicatorVisible = false
                );
            });
        }

        async void OnMessageReceived(object sender, MessageEventArgs messageEventArgs)
        {
            if (messageEventArgs.MessageType == MessageType.Chat ||
                messageEventArgs.MessageType == MessageType.Groupchat) {
                string decodedMessage = System.Net.WebUtility.UrlDecode(messageEventArgs.Message.MessageText);
                var messageTable = new MessageTable();
                messageTable.SenderId = messageEventArgs.Message.SenderId;
                messageTable.DialogId = messageEventArgs.Message.ChatDialogId;
                messageTable.DateSent = messageEventArgs.Message.DateSent;
                if (messageEventArgs.Message.NotificationType != 0) {
                    if (messageEventArgs.Message.NotificationType == NotificationTypes.GroupUpdate) {
                        if (messageEventArgs.Message.AddedOccupantsIds.Any()) {
                            var userIds = new List<int>(messageEventArgs.Message.AddedOccupantsIds);
                            userIds.Add(messageEventArgs.Message.SenderId);
                            var users = await QbChat.QbProvider.GetUsersByIdsAsync(string.Join(",", userIds));
                            var addedUsers = users.Where(u => u.Id != messageEventArgs.Message.SenderId);
                            var senderUser = users.First(u => u.Id == messageEventArgs.Message.SenderId);
                            messageTable.Text = senderUser.FullName + " added users: " + string.Join(",", addedUsers.Select(u => u.FullName));
                        } else if (messageEventArgs.Message.DeletedOccupantsIds.Any()) {
                            var userIds = new List<int>(messageEventArgs.Message.DeletedOccupantsIds);
                            var users = await QbChat.QbProvider.GetUsersByIdsAsync(string.Join(",", userIds));
                            messageTable.Text = string.Join(",", users.Select(u => u.FullName)) + " left this room";
                        }
                        //var dialogInfo = await QbChat.QbProvider.GetDialogAsync(messageEventArgs.Message.ChatDialogId);
                        //if (dialogInfo == null)
                        //{
                        //    return;
                        //}
                        //var dialog = new DialogTable(dialogInfo);
                        //Database.Instance().SaveDialog(dialog);
                    }
                } else {
                    messageTable.Text = decodedMessage;
                }

                await SetRecepientName(messageTable);

                Messages.Add(messageTable);

                InvokeOnMainThread(async () => {
                    tb_chat.ReloadData();
                    await ScrollList();
                });
            }
        }

        public async Task LoadMessages()
        {
            List<Message> messages;
            try {
                messages = await QbChat.QbProvider.GetMessagesAsync(dialogId);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
                return;
            }

            if (messages != null) {
                messages = messages.OrderBy(message => message.DateSent).ToList();
                foreach (var message in messages) {
                    var chatMessage = new MessageTable();
                    chatMessage.DateSent = message.DateSent;
                    chatMessage.SenderId = message.SenderId;
                    chatMessage.MessageId = message.Id;
                    if (message.RecipientId.HasValue)
                        chatMessage.RecepientId = message.RecipientId.Value;
                    chatMessage.DialogId = message.ChatDialogId;
                    chatMessage.IsRead = message.Read == 1;
                    await SetRecepientName(chatMessage);
                    chatMessage.Text = System.Net.WebUtility.UrlDecode(message.MessageText);
                    InvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                        Messages.Add(chatMessage)
                    );
                }

                InvokeOnMainThread(async () => {
                    tb_chat.ReloadData();
                    await ScrollList();
                });
            }
        }

        async Task SendMessageCommandExecute()
        {
            var message = MessageText != null ? MessageText.Trim() : string.Empty;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message)) {
                var m = new MessageTable();
                m.SenderId = QbChat.UserId;
                m.Text = message;
                m.DialogId = dialogId;
                m.RecepientFullName = "Me";
                try {
                    await MessageProvider.Reconnect();
                    var encodedMessage = System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(message);
                    privateChatManager.SendMessage(encodedMessage);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex);
                    return;
                }
                long unixTimestamp = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).Ticks;
                unixTimestamp /= TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond;
                m.DateSent = unixTimestamp;
                m.ID = Database.Instance().SaveMessage(m);
                var dialog = Database.Instance().GetDialog(dialogId);
                dialog.LastMessage = m.Text;
                dialog.LastMessageSent = DateTime.UtcNow;
                Database.Instance().SaveDialog(dialog, true);
                Messages.Add(m);
                MessageText = "";
                InvokeOnMainThread(async () => {
                    tb_chat.ReloadData();
                    await ScrollList();
                });
            }
        }

        public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
        {
            base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();
        }
    }
}
```

long story short the sdk receive the message but apparently fail to parse the body message. fire the handler but if empty don't call the privateChatManager.MessageReceived.

could anyone help please?
Thank you

Comment: They don't seems to fix it. I had the same problem and posted it here too without a response. My workaround was to use the extraParams ans send the text there in addition to the text message field. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40040098/how-to-get-message-text-from-xmpp-message-streem-using-quickblox-xamarin-nuget